# Web browser times out after upgrading to Angular 8

Tags: angular, browser, timeout, angular-upgrade

I have recently upgraded my web application from angular 6 to 8. Everything works fine, but sometimes I do see browser page becoming unresponsive. It never loads until I close the tab and reopen the application in new tab to continue working. I started facing this issue only after upgrade. Any kind of help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: You can use Chrome devtools to record what happens on the page for a few seconds after loading, then inspect the calling tree.

Comment: @HugoNoro i do not see any errors in console.

Comment: Any warnings during webpack compilation? Does this happen on all views or only on one particular view, with a specific component?

Comment: @HugoNoro, Could this be the cause? I get this warning everytime but page does not become unresponsive everytime.
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
    when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
Example: 
form = new FormGroup({
first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
});

Comment: No. That’s a very specific warning should not affect the page. Have you tried running lighthouse in devtools? It might raise an issue on something meaningful

Comment: @HugoNoro anything specific I need to look into when I run the light house? In the opportunities, I was advised to remove unused javascript to make page load faster

Comment: Those analytics are telling you the results against a few metrics but try to check if something is detected as a big error or an error message that it might tell you something that it’s not supposed to happen